# Find max value in a Javascript Object and print all values

Tags: javascript

I apologize but I am very new to JavaScript. I have a toy object derived from two arrays. What I want to do is find the largest value of the make parameter (i.e., make = 3) and get an object that has all the parameters (i.e., make and model ) of make equal to 3

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const myArr = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    var myCar = new Object();
    myCar.make = arr1[i];
    myCar.model = arr2[i];
    myArr.push(myCar)
}
console.log(myArr);
>>> [ { make: 1, model: 'a' },
  { make: 2, model: 'b' },
  { make: 3, model: 'c' } ]
var mm = Math.max(...myArr.map(o => o.make))
console.log(mm)
>>> 3
```

I wish `{make: 3, model: 'c'}`

Comment: find the max of arr1 Math.max(...arr1). then do arr1.findIndex to get the index for max . now u have all u need to create the object

Comment: `const max = myArr.reduce((max, curr) => max.make > curr.make ? max : curr)`